# How to render a textfield in rails haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I want to display a text field with specific parameters. When I use :

```
%input{:type=>"text", :name => "search_name",:maxlenght => "200" ,:class => "text_field", :placeholder => t("homepage.save_search.save_field_placeholder") }
```

Everything works well, and the generated html is what I want :

```
<input class="text_field" maxlenght="200" name="search_name" placeholder="Search name" type="text">
```

But when I use the following synthax :

```
=text_field :search_name, :maxlenght => "200", :class => "text_field", :placeholder => t("homepage.save_search.save_field_placeholder")
```

It generates the following html :

```
<input type="text" name="search_name[{:maxlenght=>&quot;200&quot;, :class=>&quot;text_field&quot;, :placeholder=>&quot;Search name&quot;}]" id="search_name_{:maxlenght=>&quot;200&quot;, :class=>&quot;text_field&quot;, :placeholder=>&quot;Search name&quot;}">
```

Reading other examples of rails and haml files generating text field, I thought the two solutions were equivalent. Anybody can explain the difference ?

Comment: Try replacing `= text_field ..` with `= text_field_tag ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in your former line you're creating a text field, the latter syntax is a helper used when working with objects. Have a look at the [text_field form helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field) method signature

```
text_field(object_name, method, options = {}) public
```

> For these helpers the first argument is the name of an instance variable and the second is the name of a method (usually an attribute) to call on that object. Rails will set the value of the input control to the return value of that method for the object and set an appropriate input name. If your controller has defined @person and that person's name is Henry then a form containing:

```
<%= text_field(:person, :name) %>
```

will produce output similar to

```
<input id="person_name" name="person[name]" type="text" value="Henry"/>
```

[source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects)